# Custom page template with Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, customization

I want to create a plugin with two **Pages**. Suppose, when I install this plugin, two **custom pages** will be available.

**Like**

[www.domain.com/page-1](http://www.domain.com/page-1)

[wwww.domain.com/page-2](http://wwww.domain.com/page-2)

How to do this ?? I have searched google many hours. I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please remind your question. I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: Custom pages for plugin or wordpress site?

Comment: Find out this: http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/

Comment: Hello, when I install this plugin , then two pages will be available in wordpress pages . When I uninstall this plugin , then two pages will be remove .

Answer (score 1):

Though I've not tried it for template file but you can find my gist in the link where I've loaded single.php and taxonomy.php from my plugin.
https://gist.github.com/vishalbasnet23/4cf739624ba3b75e75d8

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate this ? I don't understand how i do this . Do you understand my question ? I just want to add two page with a plugin.. When plugin active, then pages be available and when plugin deactive, then pages will remove. How ?

Comment: You can run wp_insert_post() on plugin activation hook and assign page template to the that page. After that use delete post function on plugin deactivation hook.
You can find it on my gist https://gist.github.com/vishalbasnet23/caa26a86de4b996a53c8

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when i deactivate this plugin , page not deleting and when i reinstalling this plugin , page not creating again .. Please help me .

Comment: You have to wrap the function to create page in WordPress activation hook
`code`
function myplugin_activate() {

    // Activation code here...
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

Similarly goes for decativation hook
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivate' );